# How to do object mapping in jubula?

Tags: jubula

I want to test my rcp application .For that I need to do object mapping.Can any one tell me how to do object mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cheat sheets in Jubula that take you through the basic steps to write and execute tests. In the "Help" Menu, under "Cheat Sheets" you can open the list of them. The "First Steps" Cheat Sheet is the one you need for the basic introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to add:
 -the Jubula plugin to your RCP application
 -add to config.ini the jubula bundle

Refer to:[Jubula Reference Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help/html/manual/node282.html)

> Setting up an RCP AUT for testing
>   If you want to test a Rich Client Platform application, you must first
>   unzip our "RCP Remote Control" plugin into your AUT . This can be done
>   as follows:
>
> 1. Locate the Jubula installation directory.
> 2. Extract the content of the rcp-support.zip folder into the plugins directory for your RCP AUT.
> 3. RCP applications generally have a configuration/config.ini file which contains the parameter osgi.bundles. This parameter may need to
>      be modified to allow the RCP remote control plugin to load on AUT
>      startup. The org.eclipse.update.configurator plugin automatically
>      loads all plugins found in the plugins directory, which means that the
>      RCP remote control plugin should start with the AUT if
>      org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start is already defined in the
>      osgi.bundles parameter. Otherwise, you may need to add
>      org.eclipse.jubula.rc.rcp to the end of the osgi.bundles parameter.
>
> If you do not follow the above steps, the AUT Agent will not be able
>   to communicate with your AUT!

After this, the button to add mappings should be active since the agent is able to communicate with the AUT.